# Razor dynamically render user defined tag

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

How can I achive the following?

```
    @foreach (var responsible in new List<string>{"receiver", "sender"})
    {
      <@responsible>
           ...
      </@responsible>
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is.  This code will work fine, but, the browser isn't going to know how to render this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following should work:

```
@foreach (var responsible in new List<string>{"receiver", "sender"})
{
    @Html.Raw(string.Format("<{0}>", responsible))
        @:Hello world
    @Html.Raw(string.Format("</{0}>", responsible))
}
```

By the way if you are building XML with Razor please stop immediately and use a XML parser. For example write a custom Xml action result that will be passed your model and it will take care of generating it. Razor is meant for HTML, not anything else.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'll use xml builder

Comment: @er-v - even better, use WebApi instead, which is very similar to MVC, but provides better support for web services.